# Parameter Estimation of a Poisson mixture model

Tags: estimation, matlab, poisson-distribution, mixture-distribution

I want to estimate the parameters for a Poisson mixture model with 2 (and later 3) Poisson distributions. I want to use Matlab and have numerical problems to solve the loglikelihood of the mixture model (values get to high or low).

Does anyone know how to handle this problem? I already tried to write a similar function like logLikePoisMix (https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/HTSCluster/R/logLikePoisMix.R?view=markup&root=htsfilter&sortby=rev&pathrev=60), which uses a "calculation trick from Panos" (?), but this also didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use the `mle` function to fit a pdf that you supply. You may find it beneficial to work with the exponential of the Poisson mean parameter to avoid having the optimization routine consider negative parameter values. For example:

```
>> x = [poissrnd(1,100,1); poissrnd(10,200,1)];
>> f = @(x,p,logmu1,logmu2) p*poisspdf(x,exp(logmu1)) + (1-p)*poisspdf(x,exp(logmu2));
>> mle(x,'pdf',f,'start',[.5 2 4])
ans =
    0.3440   -0.0670    2.2734
>> exp(ans(2:3))
ans =
    0.9352    9.7122
```